# Setup upgrade error Magento

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

This error appears on setup upgrade

```
| SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Cp_WishlistApi' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `setup_module` (`module`, `schema_version`) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

please clear the cache and run the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: done still same error

Answer (score 0):

It says there's already a row with 'Cp_WishlistApi' module value.

So, you can try removing it;

```
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='Cp_WishlistApi'
```

and

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```